# What information can be obtained about inverse of a matrix without inverting it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of matrices and I am interested in the properties of the inverse of these matrices individually. What kind of information can be obtained, about the inverse of the matrix, by inspecting the matrix itself?

Note: Matrices are invertible for sure.

Edit as per comments:
What can be said about the coefficient values and sign after inverting the matrix?

Comment: It depends on the property for which you are looking for. The inverse of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix. The inverse of a triangular matrix is triangular. ...

Comment: ... The inverse of an orthogonal matrix is the transpose of the matrix. The inverse of an invertible Hermitian matrix is Hermitian ...

Comment: Matrices do not possess any special nature as such.

Comment: If the Matrices have no special nature, I don't think you can assume to see some special properties of the inverse.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt can I have any information about the value of determinant via comparing the different matrices only?

Comment: @Parikshit Pareek I  don't think so. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&4\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&4\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ you get $det(A)=-3$ while $det(B)=1$. The matrices should have some property otherwise you can't assume the inverses to have some property.

Comment: $\det(A)^{-1}= \frac{1}{\det A}$ so the determinant is easy.

Comment: With Cramer's rule you can determine individual entries of the inverse using quotients of determinants.